# scroll-link effect is deprecated, what's a better alternative in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I'm currently maintaining an old legacy project, where I just noticed a message from my browser about how scroll-linked effects reduce rendering performance.

The application is rendering a large form, on the bottom there is a slider with lots of data, which will be loaded asynchronously (and only if the user scrolls down, so it gets into his view). Afterwards it creates a lot DOM-elements (a lot means a typical of 100-300 figures with an image, texts and some attributes each) that will be added into the slider.

So I was reading [about Scroll-linked effects on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects) to take care about this performance issue, but I don't know what's the best practice is. Neither I can use the examples about "sticky positioning" nor "scroll snapping". Also I do not want to customize scrolling in any way.
The goal is of this behavior is to delay loading the big bunch of data as much as possible (since only when the user scrolls this page down, he really needs this data).

Can you please help me how to take advantage on this, to optimize the scrolling performance of the application without losing the lazy-loading feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `check element visible in the viewport` + `requestAnimationframe`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/125106/800765